# Examples of ODEs with a 3-dimensional vector-function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I'm testing a program which solves ODEs and I need some examples. Where can I find some examples of ODEs with a 3-dimensional vector-funcion?

Likes these two:

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]

Comment: Guys, don't write all the answers together, it's getting hard to read everything.

Comment: It's quite many people for such busy working weekend, isn't it? :-P As for your question, you can take a look at J.C. Sprott's "Elegant Chaos: Algebraically Simple Chaotic Flows": systems there are algebraic, chaotic and with illustrations (as far as I remember).

Comment: @Evgeny, thanks! I found some examples in the book. I'd mark your answer as an 'accepted answer' if it wasn't a comment.